# How to edit a list item html/css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to make a header:

```
<ul id="umenu">
            <a href="index.html" id="lihome"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="about.html" id="liabout"><li>About</li></a>
            <a href="contact.html" id="licontact"><li>Contact</li></a>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#umenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#umenu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#lihome {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#liabout {
    background-color: #0BE0E0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#licontact {
    background-color: #1DE00B;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But when I use that, it just shows purple and blue words (text-decoration) and a grey background (from the

```
#umenu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    font-size: 30px;
```

What can I do so that I can make my header with more style?

Comment: `ul>li>a` should be the structure of your header, instead of `ul>a>li`. See http://jsfiddle.net/j5LSA/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ul id="umenu">
    <li><a href="index.html" id="lihome">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" id="liabout">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" id="licontact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
#umenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#umenu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#lihome {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#liabout {
    background-color: #0BE0E0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#licontact {
    background-color: #1DE00B;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The basic structure  of a list is as folows

```
<UL>
   <LI> ... first list item...
   <LI> ... second list item...
   ...
</UL>
```

For more detail validate your code using [**W3C Markup Validator**](http://validator.w3.org/check) will produce

```
Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

Comment: Why just copy @tewathia comment and not just upvoted it?

Comment: you should also tell the op why to do this and what is the problem in the first place

Answer (score 0):

first of, it is *required* that you put the `a` inside `li`.

Then, in CSS, you can style your links with `li a {}`. Here's my suggestion:

```
li a {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size:30;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li a:visited {
color: black;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Notice that this makes your current li and id's statement unnecessary.

[Here's the result](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/ibcfm)

Comment: `it is recommended` ***OR*** `it is required` ?